# Failed `CDLL(/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib)` - Python; Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, installation

I have the following problem: I installed the python library beautifulsoup4-4.4.1.tar.gz using the terminal. I searched for the directory it was saved in (downloads) and ran this command: python setup.py install.

Now I'm getting this message every time I run help('modules'):

> Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...
>
> Failed `CDLL(/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib)`

and can't even find the mentioned library. Can someone please tell me how to uninstall this library and then to install it again properly?

I got this too from another console:

> Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...
>
> //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/**init**.py:13:
>   ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated. You
>   should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.   "You should
>   import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
>   //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273:
>   UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This
>   may take a moment.   warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font
>   cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
>   //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py:137:
>   MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The matplotlib.delaunay module was
>   deprecated in version 1.4. Use matplotlib.tri.Triangulation instead.
>   warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
>   //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/rpy/**init**.py:11:
>   FutureWarning: The pandas.rpy module is deprecated and will be removed
>   in a future version. We refer to external packages like rpy2.  See
>   here for a guide on how to port your code to rpy2:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html
>   FutureWarning)
>   //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/filter/**init**.py:6:
>   skimage_deprecation: The `skimage.filter` module has been renamed to
>   `skimage.filters`.  This placeholder module will be removed in v0.13. 
>   warn(skimage_deprecation('The `skimage.filter` module has been renamed
>   '
>   //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/viewer/utils/core.py:11:
>   UserWarning: Recommended matplotlib backend is `Agg` for full
>   skimage.viewer functionality.   warnings.warn("Recommended matplotlib
>   backend is `Agg` for full "

Thanks in advance!

Edit: extra information from anaconda's console. I'm really new at this, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

i run into the same error

> Failed CDLL(/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib)

and fixed it by installing the *geos* package via homebrew.

`brew install geos`